# Concatenar datos en BIRT

Tags: eclipse, report

Saludos, Concatenar datos en BIRT en realidad es sencillo, el el campo data se coloca: 
Ejm:

```
dataSetRow["IMPUESTO"]+" "+(dataSetRow["PVP"]*dataSetRow["IMPUESTO"])/100
```

donde el uso del **+" "+** hace la concatenación en el BIRT, **pero** si **quiero dividir el contenido por algún carácter como debería de hacer**? porque lo que coloque arriba daría como resultado:

Teniendo como ejemplo que el impuesto es **12**, el monto sin impuesto es **200** y el resultado de **MONTO*IMPUESTO/100** es **24**

**1224.00** <<< *algo como que WTF?*

si yo quiero que en el mismo "Data" quede algo como **12 - 24 %** o **12 / 24 %**

si coloco algo dentro de los **+" / "+** no me toma la concatenación y me muestra solo el primero :( como puedo hacer que funcione?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me ha pasado que en el Data Type esta en un formato numérico por lo que se formatea a este y no toma la concatenación correctamente.

Revisa que el Tipo de dato del "DATA" sea tipo String que si acepta cualquier caracter..

**Clic Derecho sobre el "DATA" - Edit Data Binding - Data Type: String y listo!**

Jaja avísame si es tu caso.. a mi me paso >.<

Comment: Has dado en el Clavo! eso mismo era! Gracias! lo tenia en Float... lo cambie a String y funciono!